# Do lone pairs contribute towards the pi electron count of heterocycles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, aromaticity

I'm not able to understand how the following compounds are aromatic.

When should the lone pairs on heteroatoms be taken into consideration when counting the number of π electrons?

[image: Heterocycles: isoquinoline, thiophene, imidazole, thiazole]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only count the lone pairs/ pi-bonds/ groups which are participating in conjugation and ignore them in all other cases.

For example, in compound **2** (thiophene), there are two lone pairs on sulfur.

[image: Lone pairs on sulfur in thiophene]

One lone pair (brown) is in a p-orbital, and hence participates in conjugation with the two π-bonds. The other lone pair (blue) is pointing outwards from the ring in an $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital. This lone pair is orthogonal, or perpendicular, to the π-system and hence cannot take part in conjugation. In total there are six π electrons, and the compound is therefore aromatic.

See also: [Conjugated system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Nitrogen atom is already an $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized atom, so its lone pair does not take part in conjugation
2. The sulfur atom is $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized, it has two lone pairs, so only one of its lone pair will take part in conjugation for it to be $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized atom
3. $\ce{N}$ bonded to $\ce{H}$ is $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized and has its lone pair taking part in conjugation, thus its lone pair counted as 2 pi electrons. the lone pair of the $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized $\ce{N}$ atom is not pi electrons
4. Lone pair on $\ce{S}$: one pair is pi electrons, lone pair on $\ce{N}$: not pi electrons

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To help you become acquainted with the site, I would just like to suggest if you haven't already, please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies. You will find StackExchange (SE) to be a different kind of Q&A website from the mainstream. To learn more visit [Meta.Chemistry](http://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/), [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), or [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229)